# Tokenisation by date for text classification by topics

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, lda

I would need to tokenize the following column by date

```
Testo                                                         Giorno
    LE DESIGNAZIONI ARBITRALI DELLE SEMIFINALI DI RITORNO.  06/02/2020  
    La Rai ha inserito nei suoi palinsesti la diretta tv delle semifinali di ritorno di Coppa Italia, rinviate a febbraio per l'emergenza coronavirus.  06/02/2020
     Sabato Napoli-Inter completerà il quadro delle semifinali di Coppa Italia: la finale è in programma mercoledì 17 giugno all'Olimpico. 07/02/2020
    Le semifinali di ritorno e la finale di Coppa Italia si disputeranno senza i tempi supplementari    08/02/2020
```

Something like:

```
['le','designazioni','arbitrali','delle',..., 'emergenza','coronavirus'] on 6/02/2020
['Sabato','Napoli','-','Inter',...,'Olimpico'] on 7/02/2020
['Le','semifinali','di',...,'supplementari'] on 08/02/2020
```

I would need this for topics classification using LDA. 
I have tried as follows:

```
stop = stopwords.words('italian')

df_train['Testo_tok'] = df_train.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['Testo']), axis=1)
df_train['Testo_tok']= df_train['Testo_tok'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])

df_train['Testo_tok'] = df_train.groupby(['Giorno'])['Testo'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)).str.split(",")
tok_text_list=df_train['Testo_tok'].tolist()
```

However the output does not give me the expected tokenisation.

Next step would be apply the `tok_text_list to`

```
dictionary_LDA = corpora.Dictionary(tok_text_list)
dictionary_LDA.filter_extremes(no_below=10)
corpus = [dictionary_LDA.doc2bow(list_of_tokens) for list_of_tokens in tok_text_list]
corpus
```

in order to determine topics by date. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stop = stopwords.words('italian') + list(string.punctuation)
df_train['Testo_tok'] = df_train.Testo.apply(nltk.word_tokenize).apply(lambda l: [i for i in l if i not in stop])
tok_text_list = df_train.groupby(['Giorno'])['Testo_tok'].apply(sum).tolist()
```

Result of `print(*tok_text_list, sep='\n')`:

```
['LE', 'DESIGNAZIONI', 'ARBITRALI', 'DELLE', 'SEMIFINALI', 'DI', 'RITORNO', 'La', 'Rai', 'inserito', 'palinsesti', 'diretta', 'tv', 'semifinali', 'ritorno', 'Coppa', 'Italia', 'rinviate', 'febbraio', "l'emergenza", 'coronavirus']
['Sabato', 'Napoli-Inter', 'completerà', 'quadro', 'semifinali', 'Coppa', 'Italia', 'finale', 'programma', 'mercoledì', '17', 'giugno', "all'Olimpico"]
['Le', 'semifinali', 'ritorno', 'finale', 'Coppa', 'Italia', 'disputeranno', 'senza', 'tempi', 'supplementari']
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Stef. Could you please tell me, if you tried it, if when you use this list in the next step, if the corpus you get is empty?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that you have here just 3 documents and only keep tokens that are contained in at least 10 documents (`filter_extremes(no_below=10)`), so that of course nothing is kept.

Comment: I did not notice that I had not changed it! Thank you Stef